# Shortcut directly to Windows Media Center Netflix plugin

Tags: windows, automation, windows-media-center, netflix

How would I create shortcut that, when executed, would launch Windows Media Center and immediately open the Netflix plugin?

The idea would be to then link that to another application, or an external remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `.bat` file that contains:

```
Start windowsmediacenterapp:{e6f46126-f8a9-4a97-9159-b70b07890112}\{982ea9d3-915c-4713-a3c8-99a4688b7c59}?EntryPointParameters=
```

Wire your application or remote to that batch file.